# Second derivative of function evaluated along a curve on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, curves, geodesic

Let $\mathcal M$ be a Riemannian manifold and $f : \mathcal M \to \mathbb R$ be smooth. Take a smooth curve $\boldsymbol \gamma : I \to \mathcal M$, where $I$ is an open interval of the real line. I'm interested in the composition $f \circ \boldsymbol \gamma : I \to \mathbb R$.

The first derivative can be computed via the chain rule as

\begin{equation}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} (f \circ \boldsymbol \gamma) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \boldsymbol \gamma} \dot{\boldsymbol \gamma}.
\end{equation}

If I understand correctly, the first factor is the Jacobian of $f$, which in this case is a linear functional, mapping tangent vectors to scalars. Thus, the whole expression is the directional derivative of $f$ along $\dot {\boldsymbol \gamma}$. All good.

Differentiating once again, using the chain and product rule, I get

\begin{equation}
\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2} (f \circ \boldsymbol \gamma) = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \boldsymbol \gamma^2} \dot{\boldsymbol \gamma} \dot{\boldsymbol \gamma} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \boldsymbol \gamma} \ddot{\boldsymbol \gamma}.
\end{equation}

What kind of object is $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \boldsymbol \gamma^2}$? For the whole expression to be a scalar, I reckon we need $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \boldsymbol \gamma^2} \dot{\boldsymbol \gamma}$ to be a linear functional. But since $\dot{\boldsymbol \gamma}$ is just a vector, how would $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \boldsymbol \gamma^2}$ transform a vector into a linear functional?

Also, the second term is the geodesic curvature, and vansishes if $\boldsymbol \gamma$ is a geodesic, right?

Comment: Please do not write horrid things like $\partial f/\partial\boldsymbol{\gamma}$. This is an utter atrocity. Write $df_{\boldsymbol{\gamma}(t) }(\dot{\boldsymbol{\gamma}}(t))$. Forget about manifolds and work out the multivariable calculus correctly.

Comment: Consider reading a differential geometry textbook. Already your first chain rule application is wrong.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Can you please point out what I did wrong?

Comment: Do this calculation in local coordinates.

Comment: Start by reading a textbook, MSE is not a substitute for that.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I'm just asking you to point out my flaw. Just telling me "you're wrong, read a book" isn't very constructive.

Comment: @markusas I wouldn’t say wrong; just bad notation (see Ted’s comment above for how to write it correctly). Also, I should just point out that in general second derivatives aren’t that nice to deal with, but since you’re on a Riemannian manifold, you have a connection (the Levi-Civita connection) so you can take the second covariant derivative of $f$ (i.e the Hessian). The final result being $(f\circ\gamma)’’(t)=(\nabla\nabla f)(\dot{\gamma}(t),\dot{\gamma}(t))+(df)(\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}(t)}\dot{\gamma})$, i.e $[\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}(t)}(df)](\dot{\gamma}(t))+df(\ddot{\gamma}(t))$.

Comment: ^ even this formula has a bit to unpack (especially since really one should be working with pullback connections when differentiating $\dot{\gamma}$ and so on… for these details you really should read a book like Lee’s Riemannian geometry). Anyway, the object $\nabla\nabla f=\nabla(df)$ is a $(0,2)$ tensor field (which is why it is able to eat the two tangent vectors $\dot{\gamma}(t),\dot{\gamma}(t)$), which is the Hessian of $f$. And yes, the last term vanishes if $\gamma$ is a geodesic.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I see. That helps me quite a bit. Thanks very much :)